# git repo inside a repo

Tags: git, github

I accidently make a mistake in my repo, I separately pushed a folder inside my folder into another repo.  What I want is to push `folder1` back to the `mainfolder` repo, however when I try to push it I am unable to access the contents on the github user interface. I have already deleted the accidently pushed repo.  My repo is organized like this:

```
-mainfolder
   -folder1  <- I accidently pushed folder1 into another repo
   -folder2
   -folder3
   -folder4
   -README.md
```

I am getting the warning:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of    
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.        
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> folder1
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the      
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached folder1
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

Comment: Hey srty! You can delete the `.git` folder inside `folder1` to remove the inside repo association and getting `folder1` tracked by the `.git` folder in your `mainfolder`

Comment: @Thatkookooguy after deleting the `.git` file inside folder1, I still can't access the contents inside folder1, on the github ui it shows a folder with an arrow inside it.

Comment: I just had to `git rm --cached folder1` and re-add the folder for this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what the message from Git said to do! It told you:

```
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the      
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached folder1
```

So do that. To sum up:

```
rm -rf folder1/.git
git rm --cached folder1
git add folder1
```

Now commit and push.