# Remove Git Repo from a Git Repo

Tags: git, github, git-repo

I created a new repository and cloned it on my PC, then initialized a React Native App, when I try to push my code from the root folder, it is giving me an error message saying that I have another .git in my subfolder, the React Native App. There is .git directory in my subfolder as well as the root folder, but deleting the .git from the subfolder didn't make any difference, and deleting the .git directory from the root folder causes git repo in a git repo. Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you tried remove .git in subfolder and ```git add subfolder``` and ```git commit```? i think it could make a difference.

Comment: Seems the same as what I just answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67781903/341994

Answer (score 1):

.git files is always hidden files. Check your hidden files is there any extra .git file any other folders. Remove it.