# Merge git repository tracking in a sub-direcotry to that of its parent directory?

Tags: git

I have a repository for `a_project` with git repository set up, but I just realized that in a sub-directory of `a_project/src`, I have another git repository. I'd like to merge `a_project/src`'s `.git` data (history, branches, etc.) into that of `a_project`.

My purpose to merge them together is that I noticed that I cannot commit changes to files in `src`. The changes cannot be staged:

```
Unstaged changes (1)
modified   src/snmp_trap_processing
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 99ef96f28d4f74bc671ca6b2da97ecf50b84f833
+Subproject commit 581414eecb3db4bc1e572d57d1d1f8788675c372
```

I've studied in StackOverflow. The closest case is to move a repository from a subdirectory to the parent. But where the parent has no existing git repository tracking, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247756/126164
The instruction there, in my case, `a_project/src`'s `.git` will destroy the `.git` tracking at the parent directory, `a_project`.

So I wonder if there is a way to merge between the two `.git` instead of overriding one `.git` over the other?

EDIT:

I realize that in `a_project/src` the `.git` is just a file with the content below:

```
cat .git
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/src
```

So it might not be as complicated as I thought. Maybe, I can just remove the `a_project/src/.git` then it will be fine?
Maybe, also remove the submodule setup for `a_project/src` in `a_project/.git` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git repo inside a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780789/git-repo-inside-a-repo)

Comment: @matt That removes history and branches.